# How to transform a column with repeated days of the weak (from different years) in to a new column which state the week in R

Tags: r

Hello everyone i'm struggling with one step in my R thesis code. I have a column "date" from 2019-01-01 until 2020-12-30, however i have multiple row entries for the same day.
I basically want to create a new column which state the week of the year the respective row entry it belongs. Because i have 2 years i want the weeks to be cumulative, so year 2019 will have 52 weeks and the first week of 2020 will be week 53, the second week of 2020 will be week 54 and so on. In the end i should have 104 weeks.
My data set has 82 variables, but the ones that matter are the ones followed:

```
date          plays.id    name
2019-01-01     123        "Sunflower - Spider Man"
2019-01-01     456         "Without me"
2019-01-01      678        "Fly High - Shaggy"
2019-01-02     3455        "WAP"
2019-01-02     789         "Thank u, next"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and provide input using `dput` and expected output as well as any code attempt.

Comment: `format(as.Date("2019-01-01"), format = "%U")` returns `"00"`, meaning it is the first (0-based) week of the year. There are also `"%V"` and `"%W""`, depending on your weekday preferences. All of this is available in `?strptime` (perhaps not the most intuitive place, though it makes a little sense once you get used to all of the related functions). This means that `format(as.Date(yourdata$date),format="%U")` will give a string with `"00"` through `"53"`, and you can `as.integer` it if you like. From there, you can simply adjust for which year you are in.

Comment: Hey @r2evans! Thanks for the tip, i checked the info regarding the strptime and its pretty useful. I will change the format parameter to %V. However i still have the problem that when entering in the year 2020, R will see the first week of the year as 1 and i want to be 52 (51 weeks of 2019 plus 1 week of 2020).

Answer (score 1):

Some random data for my example:

```
r <- function(x) {abs(round(rnorm(x, 1000, 50)))}
dates = rep(seq(from=as.Date("2019-01-01"),to=as.Date("2021-01-01"), by=1),each = 4)
df <- data.frame(date = dates, plays.id = r(length(dates)))
```

Using `floor_date()` from `lubridate`, we create a week variable, and then calculate the difference, in weeks, from the future weeks to the first week:

```
require(lubridate)
df$week = floor_date(df$date, unit = "weeks")
df$week = as.numeric(1 + (df$week - df$week[1])/7)

> df[1:5,]
        date plays.id week
1 2019-01-01     1045    1
2 2019-01-01      974    1
3 2019-01-01     1007    1
4 2019-01-01      949    1
5 2019-01-02      966    1

> df[2000:2005,]
           date plays.id week
2000 2020-05-14     1002   72
2001 2020-05-15     1020   72
2002 2020-05-15     1034   72
2003 2020-05-15     1003   72
2004 2020-05-15      941   72
2005 2020-05-16      980   72
```

Comment: i used it and it worked! Thank you for the help

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as solved if it answered your question :)